# Flutter : forward serial ports to an emulator

Tags: android, flutter, usb

I wonder if it's possible to make visible a usb serial device (a FTDI or CDC based USB device, using for example usb_serial 0.2.3) in an Android emulator ?

When I created a new AVD in Android Studio, I didn't see anything related to that.

I found that we can forward tcp ports, example :

> adb forward tcp:6100 tcp:7100

I tried :

> adb forward usb:COM3 usb:COM3

but I get :

> cannot bind listener: unknown socket specification 'usb:COM3'

I also found some doc here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/268068f25673242d1d5130d96202d3288c91b700/adb/sockets.cpp

but I'm not sure if it's something possible.

Any idea ?

---

**I found a workaround :**

I tried to find a way to debug more efficiently an app without having to unplug the serial device connected on the phone and to plug it to a computer to refresh the app.

I found that it's possible to debug remotely an app, so that solved the problem (the serial device staying connected to the phone).

***To debug in wifi, the solution was :***

I plugged-in the phone, then run :

```
  adb tcpip 5555
  adb connect 192.168.1.3
```

and finally I unplugged the phone.

that did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a way to debug more efficiently an app without having to unplug the serial device connected on the phone and to plug it to a computer to refresh the app.

I found that it's possible to debug remotely an app, here is how I did :

```
1) plug the phone to your desktop, then run :

2) adb tcpip 5555

3) adb connect 192.168.1.3 (ip of your mobile)

4) unplug your phone

5) You're done, you can now debug remotely your app.
```

that solved the problem.